# Localhost App Testing on IE11 VM does not show app styling

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, localhost, internet-explorer-11

When troubleshooting my React app on a VirtualBox Ie11 VM, the styling of my app doesn't show up. I'm running the app locally on my Mac, and when I connect to the localhost on my Mac it works fine, but through the VM localhost connection, styling doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to enable 'Accessing data sources across domains' option in custom level security setting to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not. https://i.postimg.cc/brFBJW7r/208.png

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT That didn't seem to fix it, any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use the developer tools to check whether files get downloaded or not. check it's status code. You can also try to use the fiddler to see whether it showing any issue there. For testing purpose, Try to enable that 'Accessing data sources across domains' in intranet zone too. If possible than make similar settings for all the security zones and try to test with lower settings just for testing purpose..